# Including all info from an accumulating snapshot table in a dimension table?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, data-warehouse

I've created an accumulated snapshot fact table for steps that a customer takes to register -- e.g., time of each step, time between steps.

If I want a very rich customer dimension, could I include all of the columns that come from the accumulated snapshot table? or is that redundant?

If I include the columns from the accumulated snapshot in the customer dimension, what's the point of having a fact table for the process? If I don't include the columns, I won't be able to filter as easily using my customer dimension.

Answer (score 4):

Often adding "near-real-time" metrics to a customer dimension is useful for analytics when you want to answer questions like "What is total net sales made in the last 7 days by customers with lifetime spend > $1000?".

Storing this data in the accumulating snapshot sets up a multi-step ETL process:

1. Load Transaction Fact Table
2. Load Customer Dimension, keeping yesterday's metrics.
3. Load Accumulating Snapshot
4. Update Customer Dimension with new lifetime metrics. Alternately, create a view that Pre-joins the customer dim with this snapshot table.

You have the option to do this as part of the customer dimension build, but separating out the table into the accumulating snapshot is useful for analytics directly on that snapshot table.

For example, if my accumulating snapshot is "Total Lifetime Customer Sales by Product", I can pull Total Lifetime sales across all products from this and put it on my customer dim (probably faster than re-querying the transaction fact again). I still want to be able to use the fact for product by customer analytics as well.

If your accumulating snapshot is at the grain of customer *only*, I could see just doing the build directly on the customer dim. But usually it's useful to have it at a lower grain so other things can be done with it.